# Use ~.ssh/config to always set TERM=cygwin for certain hosts?

Tags: ssh, windows-server-2008, environment-variables

I use WinSSHd on several Windows servers. To access them from my Mac (and presumably, just about any Unix-based terminal), I need to set the `TERM` environment variable to `cygwin`, e.g.:

```
TERM=cygwin ssh someserver.com
```

I can also use the `.ssh/config` to set certain defaults for that server, such as a different user and non-default port:

```
host someserver.com
    User SomeDifferentDude
    Port 22222
```

However, I apparently can't set environment variables that way. I haven't found anything in `man ssh_config`, anyway. **Is there a way to set the default terminal emulation (and/or any environment variable) per host?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out there's a much better solution — WinSSHd supports Unix's `terminfo` format, so all I had to do is copy the proper `terminfo` file (in the case of OS X: xterm-color) into its directory, and the `TERM=cygwin` setting become unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

You would typically set the environment variable on the server side.

If WinSSHd is sufficiently like openssh (the usual unix implementation of ssh), you can define an environment file (`~/.ssh/environment` on unix) and put `TERM=cygwin` there.

You can also set the environment variable in your shell initialization file. Since you mention cygwin, this is presumably `~/.bash_profile` where `~` is your cygwin home directory. You should set it conditionally, in case you also use cygwin on other terminal types; for example, to set it only if you are logging in over ssh (again, assuming WinSSHd is sufficiently like openssh):

```
if [ -n "$SSH_CLIENT" ]; then
  export TERM=cygwin
fi
```

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't find a way to set environment variables in its server settings, but ended up finding a much better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SendEnv TERM` to set the TERM on the server to be the same as the TERM on your local machine.